# How to add wiki page when click add a page from settings icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

[image]

Hi Im new to SharePoint.How do I change setting so when i click add a page button from setting icon, i can create a wiki page not a site page.Thanks

right now site page create like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Site Settings**, there will be a library called "**Site Pages**" which is default library for all pages you create in SharePoint.

You can add Web Part Pages into this library by clicking **File -> New Document -> Web Part Page** and edit the pages as you like.

If you just select add new document, by default SharePoint will create a Wiki Page for you.

Comment: Hi harshal,Thanks for the answer.By default SharePoint used to create Wiki pages but maybe be because some changes to settings when i create a new page site page will create not a wiki page.

Comment: You can create 2 types of pages in SharePoint, Wiki Page or Web Part Page.